# Remove values from NSMutableArray which are empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have this array and I want to delete the values that have @"" or nothing inside. I want to keep the array with the values and with his new length. 
How is this possible?

```
array:{
"24_7" = 1;
"abo_ok" = "";
city = "";
"compte_ok" = "";
country = FR;
"credit_card" = "Mastercard, Visa";
"date_creation" = "2011-11-05 18:01:56";
"debut_abo" = "";
dst = "992.565700179622";
email = "";
"fin_abo" = "";
"h_saturday" = "";
"h_sunday" = "";
"h_week" = "";
handicapped = "Malades assis";
hours = "";
id = 614;
"id_driver" = 614;
"info_compl" = "";
languages = "";
"location_lat" = "48.6823";
"location_long" = "6.17818";
luggage = 0;
luxury = "";
name = "Taxi";
nbvotes = "";
passengers = 4;
query = 8;
score = 9;
"special_trip" = "A\U00e9roport, Colis";
status = 2;
"tel_1" = 0383376537;
"tel_2" = "";
vehicles = "";
votes = "";
}
```

Comment: Looks more like NSDictionary!

Comment: Yes I think so, but can't arrive to remove the empty ones

Comment: In that case please change the title of your question from NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary!

Comment: Also, this answer will get you through http://stackoverflow.com/a/9446317/365188

Answer (score 10):

```
[myMutableArray removeObject: @""];
```

Removes **all** occurrences of `@""` from the array.  [Docs for -removeObject here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBB).

Also if you really have a mutable dictionary as alluded to in the comments

```
NSArray* keysToGo = [myDictionary allKeysForObject: @""];
[myDictionary removeObjectsForKeys: keysToGo];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array];
[set removeObject:@""];
NSArray *result =[set allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and remove each string with a length of 0:

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < array.count; idx++) {
    if([[array objectAtIndex:idx] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { //type check
        if(((NSString*)[array objectAtIndex:idx]).length == 0) { //test for string length

            //finally, pull out that string
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:idx]; 

            //because we removed an object, we have to decrement the 
            //counter to avoid skipping the next string
            idx--; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the ugly type cast by not using dot syntax. `[[array objectAtIndex:idx] length]`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but for some reason a part of me NEEDS to use dot syntax for properties ALWAYS, and another part of me needs to use Smalltalk messaging syntax for methods ONLY... call it OCD...

Comment: Ha! Some part of me NEEDS to use messaging syntax always because dot syntax should have been euthanised at birth (partly for this very reason). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through entire array and check the length for each value.If the length of value is <=0, then remove that object from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableArray's removeObjectIdenticalTo: method, as follows

```
[yourMutArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```

to remove the null values. 
No need to iterate.