# NSArray not removing objects

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, nsarray

I have 5 objects in Array and want to delete 2 in loop but I have a small minor problem in below code

```
NSMutableArray *totalPages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[totalPages addObject:@"Test1"];
[totalPages addObject:@"Test2"];
[totalPages addObject:@"Test3"];
[totalPages addObject:@"Test4"];
[totalPages addObject:@"Test5"];

int currentPage = 2;

for (int x = 0; x < [totalPages count]; x++) {

    //int pageIds = [[totalPages objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
    //NSLog(@"%d",pageIds);

    NSLog(@"Array Count %d", (int)[totalPages count]);
    NSLog(@"Current Page %d", currentPage);
    NSLog(@"Current Iterator Value %d", x);

    if (x > currentPage) {

        [totalPages removeObjectAtIndex:x];

        NSLog(@"Array Count %d", (int)[totalPages count]);
        NSLog(@"Number of Pages to be removed %d", x);
    }
}
```

As I want to delete "Test4" and "Test5"   but my above code is deleting only "Test5" and if I keep this logic as

```
if (x >= currentPage)
```

so it deletes my "Test4" and "Test5" objects but logic fails when int currentPage = 0;   so what is the recommended approach to delete Test4 and Test5 as objects in arrays are dynamically added and when  currentPage = 0;  so Arrays has only 1 Object in it as a pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remove from NSMutableArray while iterating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111866/best-way-to-remove-from-nsmutablearray-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is changing as you deleting elements from it, it is getting shortened.

Adjust your for statement and count backwards, that should solve the problem for you.