# Fastest way of filter an NSArray of NSArrays by multiple indexes

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsarray, xcode8

I am on XCode 8.2, OSX not iOS, Objective-C

I have an NSMutableArray with NSMutableArrays like this

```
@[
    @[@"value1",@"value2",@"value3",@"value4",@"value4"],
    @[@"value1",@"value2",@"value3",@"value4",@"value4"],
    @[@"value1",@"value2",@"value3",@"value4",@"value4"]
]
```

The values inside are completely dynamic. The above example is for demonstration. I need to filter these NSMutableArrays inside by multiple indexes. So - given indexes 1 and 3 the result should look like this

```
@[
    @[@"value2",@"value4"],
    @[@"value2",@"value4"],
    @[@"value2",@"value4"]
]
```

I already have a functional method with iterating over every array and removing the unneeded items at the corresponding indexes but this is very slow - so any recommendation to speed things up is welcome.

My current solution:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
[indexes addIndex:1];
[indexes addIndex:3];

for (NSMutableArray* theArray in allArrays)
    [theArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove from NSMutableArray while iterating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111866/best-way-to-remove-from-nsmutablearray-while-iterating)

Comment: and you might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/126088/793428).

Comment: `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` or `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` might be faster.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever This question is not a duplicate. The enumerated array isn't modified. Is the linked answer faster than `removeObjectsAtIndexes:`?

Comment: @Willeke depending on your use case, yes, `removeObjectsAtIndexes` is considered to be the worst solution in terms of time complexity because for each deletion, it requires a lot of shifting operation to be made.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever And in this case?